# C++ thread no overloaded function takes X arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a problem with starting a thread in my program. I have a class, which looks like this:

```
class quicksort {
private:
    // Array parameters
    int length;
    // Actual sorting functions
    template <typename T>
    void _sort(T* data, int, int);
    template <typename T>
    int _partition(T* data, int, int);
    template <typename T>
    void _swap(T* data, int, int);
    void test_partition(int* data, int length);

public:
    // Constructors
    quicksort() {}

    // Sorting functions
    template <typename T>
    void sort(T* data, int len);

    void test();
};
```

The `_sort()` method looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
void quicksort::_sort(T* data, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        auto q = _partition(data, p, r);
        std::thread lower(&quicksort::_sort, this, data, p, q - 1);
        std::thread upper(&quicksort::_sort, this, data, q + 1, r);
        lower.join();
        upper.join();
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Frynio\Dropbox\Studia\ZSSK\Projekt\quicksort\include/quicksort.hpp(55): error C2661: 'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 5 arguments
C:\Users\Frynio\Dropbox\Studia\ZSSK\Projekt\quicksort\include/quicksort.hpp(41): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void quicksort::_sort<T>(T *,int,int)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
../src/main.cpp(8): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void quicksort::sort<int>(T *,int)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
C:\Users\Frynio\Dropbox\Studia\ZSSK\Projekt\quicksort\include/quicksort.hpp(56): error C2661: 'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 5 arguments
```

55 and 56 are the lines, where I start the threads. I can't seem to understand what am I doing wrong. I think that the argument passing is okay, so I thought that the problem might be, that `data` is of type `T`, this is a template method. Is that it? And if it is, is there a way around it?

Comment: Have you included `thread`? Also what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I did. I want to implement my own version of quicksort with usage of threads, so I can speed it up (of course later I will add a thread count limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write (with the `<T>`)

```
std::thread lower(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, p, q - 1);
std::thread upper(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, q + 1, r);
```

Otherwise how will the compiler deduce which instantiation of `_sort` you want to pass to the `std::thread` constructor? Indeed, when I compile your code with clang 7.0, I get the following additional error:

```
thread:118:7: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Callable'
      thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
      ^
```

So that indicates that it can't determine the type of `&quicksort::sort`.